# SwiftUI UIImagePickerController adds Black Bars in Landscape

Tags: ios, xcode, swiftui

I have a SwiftUI app with SwiftUI App lifecycle where the user can take photos of items
and store those images in the app persistent store. With one exception, the app
performs as expected. Both iPhone and iPad are supported. The exception is with photos
taken on an iPad in landscape mode. Those photos have a black band at the top and bottom
of the photo. I think that Apple only supports the portrait type capture, which would
be fine if I could crop the image to remove those bands. I've seen some older posts with this same issue, but none of the suggestions seems to apply now. I have not found any way to
eliminate the blackened area. I think my capture code is pretty standard.

In this image the green is what I get. The red is what I want.

[image]

```
struct CaptureImageView: View {
    @Binding var isShown: Bool
    @Binding var newUIImage: UIImage?

    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        return Coordinator(isShown: $isShown, image: $newUIImage)
    }
}

extension CaptureImageView: UIViewControllerRepresentable {

    func makeUIViewController(context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<CaptureImageView>) -> UIImagePickerController {

        let vc = UIImagePickerController()
    
        if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(UIImagePickerController.SourceType.camera) {
            vc.sourceType = .camera
            vc.allowsEditing = true
            vc.cameraCaptureMode = .photo
            vc.delegate = context.coordinator

            return vc
        }
        return UIImagePickerController()
    }

    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: UIImagePickerController, context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<CaptureImageView>) {
    }

}//extension

class Coordinator: NSObject, UINavigationControllerDelegate, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate {

    @Binding var isCoordinatorShown: Bool
    @Binding var imageInCoordinator: UIImage?

    init(isShown: Binding<Bool>, image: Binding<UIImage?>) {
        _isCoordinatorShown = isShown
        _imageInCoordinator = image
    }

    func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {

        guard let unwrapImage = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.editedImage] as? UIImage else { return }

        imageInCoordinator = unwrapImage
        isCoordinatorShown = false

    }//image picker controller

    func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(_ picker: UIImagePickerController) {
        isCoordinatorShown = false
    }

}//class
```

Any guidance would be appreciated. Xcode 14.3, iOS 14.3

Comment: that black border is not part of the image which gets saved, it's only visible in the picker

Comment: Sadly, that is not my experience.

Comment: that's weird. does `UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.originalImage` work instead? looks like a cropping issue

Comment: Interesting. At first glance it looks like it does. The image is no longer square, but I may be able to deal with that. Let me look at all of the other situations, iPhone,portrait, retake etc and I'll post a followup comment.

Comment: With a small sample set - it sure looks like this removes the black bands. I would still like to crop to square, so the trade-off is the wrong shape and a piece of photo or the right shape but black bands. Both phone and pad now have rectangular images - portrait or landscape depending on the device orientation. I have to think on this.